# WCF and DI and Business logic layer, How to expose all methods of BLL, Best practice

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, dependency-injection

I have

```
Public Class AuthorBLL : IAuthorBLL
{
    Public Add_Author();
    Public Get_AuthorsList();
}

Public Class BookBLL : IBookBLL
{
    Public Add_Book();
    Public Get_BookList();
}
```

Now I want to call my Business logic layer methods in my WCF layer and want to expose similar WCF OperationContracts methods to the UI.

My WCF class looks like this:

```
Public class WCFService : IWCFService
{
    private IAuthorBLL _authorBLL;
    private IBookBLL _BookBLL;


        public WCFService(IAuthorBLL authorBll, IBookBLL bookBll)
        {
            _authorBLL = authorBll;
         _bookBll = bookBll;    
        }   


    Public WCF_Add_Author (serializable_author author);
    {
        _authorBLL.Add_Author();
}

Public WCF_Get_AuthorsList()
{
    _authorBLL.Get_AuthorList();

}


Public WCF_Add_Book (serializable_book book);
    {
        _bookBll.Add_Book();
}

Public WCF_Get_BookList()
{
    _bookBll.Get_BookList();

}

}
```

Question:

My question is regarding the WCF constructor where i have to pass all these Business logic layer objects as constructor parameters to achieve DI. How can i make it generic so that if in the future I have publisherBLL, VentorBLL, CustomerBLL and so on... i don’t have to pass them all in the WCF constructor?

I know it’s the way dependency injection works but what if i have 50 BLL objects; will i have to pass them all in the WCF constructor. Is there any way to avoid it? Any design pattern or technique which can give me better solution to this.

I need to keep one WCF service which can expose all method whether its Authors, books, publishers, clients, customers or retailers. One service should expose all CRUD methods.

---

EDit:
As you are saying use Ninjet or CastleWinsor for IOC where you can create the containers to define DI. but still you have to define the constructor based parameters in the WCF constructor in WCF class.

Do we will have to define the constructor parameters as below. or if the WCF is too big to expose so many methods then what is a solution for an application where you have to do CRUD for Authors, books, employees (working in a shop), publishers, HR and payroll modules. every module have webpages and calling WCF service to do CRUD. as we never know when we will need to move on to Mobile interface or how many other applications will use the same methods so we want to expose all through WCF service. What should i do?

```
private IAuthorBLL _authorBLL;
    private IBookBLL _BookBLL;
    private IClientBll _ClientBll;
    private IPublisherBll _PublisherBll;
    private IHRBll _HRBll;
    private IEmployeeBll _employeeBll;
```

public WCFService(IAuthorBLL authorBll, IBookBLL bookBll, IClientBll 
            clientBll, IPublisherBll publisherBll, IEmployeeBll 
            employeeBll, IHRBll HRBll)
        {
            _authorBLL = authorBll;
         _bookBll = bookBll;
            _authorBLL = authorBll;
         _ClientBll = clientBll;
            _PublisherBLL = publisherBll;
         _HRBll = HrBll;
            _EmployeeBLL = EmployeeBll;

```
    }
```

As i have so many front end pages to deal with employees, authors, clients, books, publishers. What should i do.

Comment: If you're creating a service that needs 50 bll objects, you should think about re-factoring that service as it's probably doing to much.

Comment: Thanks Simon, but how would you do it? if you have 20 tables and 4 CRUD methods for each table in the BLL then 20 Web pages to create, delete and show those tables data. You will need to expose all those through the WCF or what you suggest to handle this. Database is huge and there are so many web pages to store and retrive the static information. Think of a huge HR+Payroll system. what would you do please?

Comment: I would create a number of smaller services. This should keep the complexity down as well as your services now target smaller pieces of functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've pretty much answered yourself. If you use some `DI` framework like [Unity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649614.aspx) or [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) then you won't have to bother about passing `50` arguments to your constructor - just retrieve the service object from the `DI` framework's factory and it will care about providing appropriate arguments. Maybe what are you missing is that you can register your service in the DI framework along with it's dependencies.

Simple example with Unity:

> In some kind of a Bootstrapper class which initializes whole application:

```
public void Run()
{
  //...
  SetupContainer();
  //...
  RunWebService();
  //...
}

public void SetupContainer()
{
  //This can also be done using a configuration file

  this.container.RegisterType<IAuthorBLL, AuthorBLLImpl>();
  this.container.RegisterType<IBookBLL, BookBLLImpl>();
  this.container.RegisterType<IOther1BLL, Other1BLLImpl>();
  //...
  this.container.RegisterType<IOther50BLL, Other50BLLImpl>();
}

public void RunWebService()
{
  this.container.RegisterType<IWCFService, WCFService>(
      new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

  var serviceSingleton = this.container.Resolve<IWCFService>();

  //... proceed with service setup and run
}
```

Note that usually `SetupContainer` is split between different modules. Each of them registers its own classes.